# Grep key-value pairs from a badly formatted plaintext file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, cygwin

I am writing a shell script which needs to retrieve key-value pairs from badly
formatted plaintext `.txt` files. The `.txt`s are MS Word documents which have
been saved as plaintext. As you can see from the sample below
`Sample_Profile.txt`, keys are succeeded by values which have been delimited by
opening and closing parentheses.

```
User First Name

(Goofball)

User Last Name

(Goofberg) Email Address

(goofball@example.com)

Password (sogoofedrightnow)

1. Profile details

Profile name*  (Goofball's Profile) Profile Id**
(Guid2763944-a234)
```

The only problem seems to be ignoring white-space and empty lines when matching
a key to its value. In summary, what I would like to do is specify the key (e.g.
"User First Name" or "Profile Name") and `grep` only the corresponding value,
and finally pipe to my `sed` so I get the values I need.

Here is the script I have written which is meant to get the value for "User
First Name".

```
FIRST_NAME=$(grep "User First Name" Sample_Profile.txt | sed 's|[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*|\1|') 
#grep User First Name key and pipe to sed to get the value bewteen parentheses
sed -i -e 's/USER_FIRST_NAME/'"$FIRST_NAME"'/g' UserName.txt 
echo $FIRST_NAME 
# outputs "User First Name" when it should get "Goofball" (grep is not
# piping correctly due to white space)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '/User First Name/ {print $2}' RS=')' FS='('
```

Output:

```
Goofball
```